# Spawned Ruby process on Windows dies when shell is terminated

Tags: ruby, windows, shell, powershell, spawn

I am trying to spawn a Ruby process on Windows using something like this:

```
p1 = spawn('ruby', 'loop.rb', [:out, :err] => ['process.log', "w"],  :new_pgroup => true)
```

I also then detach from the process via:

```
p1.detach
```

This should as far I understand create a new process which is independent of the parent. I am even using new_pgroup parameter to make sure that new process gets its own process group.

When I execute my script, the sub-process gets started and keeps running. The execution of the script spawning the sub process also completes. However, when I now close the shell, the sub-process dies. I would expect it to continue running (it does on OS X and Linux). I cannot figure out whether this is a bug in the Ruby runtime on Windows or whether this is a limitation of Windows and how it handles processes.

For completeness the full Ruby code of what I am trying to do:

---

**spawner.rb**: can be executed via `ruby spawner.rb` and just spawns a new sub-process. The process creates is *loop.rb* which is just an endless loop. Depending on the OS it specifies a different parameter for the process group creation.

```
require "tempfile"
require 'rbconfig'

class SpawnTest

  def self.spawn_process

    if os == :windows
      p1 = spawn('ruby', 'loop.rb', [:out, :err] => ['process.log', "w"],  :new_pgroup => true)
    else
      p1 = spawn('ruby', 'loop.rb', [:out, :err] => ['process.log', "w"],  :pgroup => true)
    end

    # Detach from the processes so they will keep running
    puts p1
    Process.detach(p1)
  end

  def self.os
    @os ||= (
    host_os = RbConfig::CONFIG['host_os']
    case host_os
      when /mswin|msys|mingw|cygwin|bccwin|wince|emc/
        :windows
      when /darwin|mac os/
        :macosx
      when /linux/
        :linux
      when /solaris|bsd/
        :unix
      else
        raise Error::WebDriverError, "unknown os: #{host_os.inspect}"
    end
    )
  end
end

if __FILE__ == $0
  SpawnTest.spawn_process
end
```

---

**loop.rb**

```
$stdout.sync = true
$stderr.sync = true

i = 0
while i < 10000
  $stdout.puts "Iteration #{i}"
  sleep 1
  i = i + 1
end

$stdout.puts "Bye from #{Process.pid}"
```

---

I found the [win32-process](https://github.com/djberg96/win32-process/) gem during my investigations. It seems to be using win32 API calls to spawn processes. Does anyone know whether this library would fix the problem?

Any help appreciated.

Comment: For what it's worth, the win32-process gem solves my problem. Using it, I can create sub processes on Windows which don't die when I close the terminal. I still don't know whether the problem I see with Kernel.spawn on Windows is due to a bug, wrong options or some unknown to me "feature" of Windows.

Comment: Can you confirm that the spawned processes are actually created in separate groups using a tool like [Process Explorer](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/processexplorer.aspx)?

Comment: I assume you mean the TaskManager!? I don't seem to be able to view the PGID there. I only see the process id. Any idea how to get the PGID for a running process on Windows? I tried with Cygwin and 'ps -W' and I can see the process and a column for PGID, but it is pretty much '0' for all processes regardless. I don't think this output is reliable.

Comment: No, I mean Process Explorer, the tool I provided a link to. It does display process trees as opposed to stock Task Manager.

Comment: Sorry, my wrong. Let me try.

Comment: I cannot see a actual PGID somewhere either, but if the tree display is a hint, then the process appears in the root of the tree. In the properties I can see "Parent: <Non-existent Process>(1128)" which seems right as well. The Ruby process from which I spawned the process has terminated. Still, if I close the terminal, the process dies.

Comment: Just in case, which key combination do you use to close the shell?

Comment: I use the button to close the shell. It actually then asks me whether I want to close the terminal due to still running processes and I need to confirm at this stage. Seem the spawned process is somehow a child of the terminal!?

Comment: Oh, that makes a lot of sense then. Let me just finish my answer.

Answer (score 4):

I couldn't find any use of process groups in Windows except for dispatching `CTRL` events to multiple processes as it states in [Process Creation Flags MSDN docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684863(v=vs.85).aspx):

> Process groups are used by the GenerateConsoleCtrlEvent function to enable sending a CTRL+BREAK signal to a group of console processes.

What actually happens when `CREATE_NEW_PROCESS_GROUP` flag is specified is...

> ...an implicit call to SetConsoleCtrlHandler(NULL,TRUE) is made on behalf of the new process; this means that the new process has CTRL+C disabled. This lets shells handle CTRL+C themselves, and selectively pass that signal on to sub-processes. CTRL+BREAK is not disabled, and may be used to interrupt the process/process group.

[From CreateProcess MSDN docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682425(v=vs.85).aspx).

Note that this is not the same as closing the console window with the `x` button. In the latter case the process receives `CTRL_CLOSE_EVENT`,

> A signal that the system sends to all processes attached to a console when the user closes the console (either by clicking Close on the console window's window menu, or by clicking the End Task button command from Task Manager).

[From HandlerRoutine callback MSDN docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683242(v=vs.85).aspx).

Handling of this event is not affected by `SetConsoleCtrlHandler(NULL,TRUE)` set by `CREATE_NEW_PROCESS_GROUP` flag when creating the process.

All above means `CREATE_NEW_PROCESS_GROUP` flag has nothing to do with the behaviour you are observing.

By default a child process [inherits](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683463(v=vs.85).aspx) parent's console window and IO handles. Therefore when you close the shell by clicking on the `x` button, it receives `CTRL_CLOSE_EVENT` and does not have an option to not terminate.

To avoid that, the child process should not be attached to the parent console. This is done by supplying `DETACHED_PROCESS` flag to `CreateProcess` Windows API.

> By default, a console process inherits its parent's console
>   ...
>   Console processes are not attached to a console if they are created using CreateProcess with DETACHED_PROCESS.

[From Creation of a Console MSDN docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682528(v=vs.85).aspx).

This is what I believe Ruby's `spawn` and `win32-process` gem do differently. I haven't try to debug both in order to see the specific difference in the flags they supply to `CreateProcess` although that would be an interesting thing to do.

There are other ways to create a child process without inheriting the console or IO handles of the parent. Examples are `CREATE_NO_WINDOW` or `CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE` flags, [Job Objects](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684161(v=vs.85).aspx), etc.

Comment: Wau, awesome answer and makes a lot of sense as well. The win32-process has indeed the option Process::DETACHED_PROCESS which I am using in the updated code. Unfortunately there are no other documented flags in Kernel.spawn apart of the :new_pgroup flag which one could use to control the process creation. Sounds like a shortcoming/bug in the Ruby VM. It either needs to expose more Windows specific options or set DETACHED_PROCESS per default. One would need to check the actual impl of Kernel.spawn. Seems win32-process is the only option for now.

Comment: Well, Ruby is primarily popular on Unix-like platforms. With Windows support not being a priority and the vast conceptual difference of the Windows API, I'd say `spawn` uses quite sensible approach when invoked on Windows. After all, a standalone window-less process is frowned in upon in its habitat unless it is a system service.

Comment: I agree Windows seems to be a second class citizen. I also agree that in the Windows world a system service would probably preferred, but that makes things even more tricky/divergent if you want to write code for all OS types. Regarding the defaults. It seems odd to already offer Windows specific flags, but nothing to control this behavior and if nothing else the documentation should be more explicit about difference. Anyways, at least now we know :-)